# ListBox.SelectedItems not refreshing in Style binding for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, listbox

I'm trying to learn WPF for my new job and an initial task for me was to build a mutliselect ComboBox. I know there are lots of different approaches for that but I tried to implement mine to develop myself. Though in theis process, I couldn't manage to successfully bind the ListBox.SelectedItems to a TextBox successfully. Actually I think I could bind, since the Converter is triggered initially, though as the SelectedItems change, the binding is not refreshed. Below, you can find the style and the converter I implemented. Is there another trick I should do to refresh the binding or is this approach impossible at all?

Thanks & Regards,
Erdi

## Style

```
<Style 
        TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" 
        x:Key="ComboListBox">
        <Style.Resources>
            <global:VisibilityContentConverter x:Key="VisibilityContentConverter"/>
            <global:ListStringConverter x:Key="ListStringConverter"/>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding ElementName=ItemsList, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityContentConverter}}" />
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Extended"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding ElementName=ItemsList, Path=SelectedItems, Converter={StaticResource ListStringConverter}, Mode=OneWay, BindsDirectlyToSource=True}"></TextBox>
                                <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" Name="Tog" />
                            </Grid>
                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="ItemsList" Visibility="Collapsed" SelectionMode="Extended"></ListBox>
                            <Button Content="Erdi"></Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
```

## Converter

```
class SelectedItemsToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object     parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var val in (IList)value)
            {
                sb.Append(val + " ");
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your ViewModel, it could be missing ChangeNotification when you are setting SelectedItems

Comment: Well I just add this Style to a ListBox and give 
public ObservableCollection<string> Items = new ObservableCollection<string>() {"1", "2"};
as Binding to collection. I believe this Binding should be done in the Style though. Do I have to create ViewModel for this?

Comment: Can't the Style handle the binding between its items via refreshing them?

Comment: I don't get it. You are binding View with what if not ViewModel? Where this this ObservableCollection is declared?

Comment: On the MainWindow.xaml.cs as

 public ObservableCollection<string> Items = new ObservableCollection<string>() {"1", "2"}; 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = Items;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

Comment: On and the xaml of MainWindow I have this

Comment: <ListBox Style="{StaticResource ComboListBox}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />

Comment: You should incorporate these comments in the question, so they would be more readable.

Comment: From what I can see, the main issue is binding to SelectedItems of ListBox. This property isn't a normal dependency property you can bind to. Even you acheived binding using mode=oneway, it seems that change notifications are not set anyway.

Comment: Then would you have any suggestions on how to bind them anyway?

Comment: I think the most common case would be to have "IsSelected" property on each item of list box. Then in the ViewModel you would have your own "SelectedItems" property that will do something like `Items.Where(x=>x.IsSelected)`. And you will have binding to this property instead of SelectedItems of ListBox.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in a Style?